# TargetInvocationException while calling PHP webservice

Tags: c#, php, web-services, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am creating Windows Phone 8 app. I need to call PHP web service which returns me JSON. When I call the service I am getting `TargetInvocationException`. Details & code is given below. I tried to call the same web service in Windows 8 app using `HttpClient`, it's working fine.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValidData())
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(LOGIN_URL, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Password))); 
    }
}

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var aa = e.Result; //Exception is here
}

An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Inner Exception Details:

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

Comment: Well, the error is quite explicit: `The remote server returned an error: NotFound`. See why the phone can't reach this address and/or why the server returns an error code